# How do I implement the Websocket Handshake into this server?

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, twisted

I need to implement the Websocket Handshake into my Python server. My python server is using Twisted for it's event handling. I have found [this webpage](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/export/29073/branches/websocket-4173-2/doc/web/howto/websocket.xhtml) that explains the process, however I truly am over my head when it comes to this. So how do I implement the Websocket handshake into the below server code: (Heads up, I've taken out all my project specific code from the server to make it easier to read)

```
import os
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor


class IphoneChat(Protocol):

    def connectionMade(self):
        #self.transport.write("""connected""")
        #self.factory.clients.append(self)
        print "A new client has connected"

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        for c in self.factory.clients:
            if c == self:
                self.factory.client.remove(self)


        print "client disconnected"

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        #print "Message Received: ", data


    def message(self, message):
        self.transport.write(message + '\n')


factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = IphoneChat
factory.clients = []


port = 3000
print "Server started: "
print port


reactor.listenTCP(port, factory)

reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that the page you found is for documentation for an in-development feature that is not yet actually part of Twisted.  You won't be able to use anything you read about on that page without taking special extra steps you probably don't want to have to take.

Next, take a look at http://autobahn.ws/python/ which provides a Twisted-friendly Python library for writing WebSockets clients.